# Stripe - Can't create payment intent

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get a basic setup of a server which accepts payments using Stripe. I'm following this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android&ui=custom#android-google-pay   My server is written in Java and the client is in Android.

I understand that the server has to create a paymentintent and send a client secret associated with the paymentintent to the client. The problem I'm facing is that `PaymentIntent.create()` gets stuck, and I don't know why. Here's the entire server program.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    post("/payment-sheet", (request, response) -> {
        Stripe.apiKey = "TESTSECRETKEY";
        System.out.println("1");
        PaymentIntentCreateParams params =
        PaymentIntentCreateParams.builder()
            .setAmount(1099L)
            .setCurrency("sek")
            .addPaymentMethodType("card")
            .build();
        System.out.println("2");

        PaymentIntent intent = PaymentIntent.create(params); /*The program doesn't get past this line */
        System.out.println("3");

        String clientSecret = intent.getClientSecret();
        System.out.println("4");
        System.out.println(clientSecret);

        Map<String, String> responseData = new HashMap();
        responseData.put("paymentIntent", clientSecret);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(responseData);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is your Android code that calls your `/payment-sheet` endpoint? Have you adding any logging to understand why your creation request is failing? Equally, check the logs on your [Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs) as there may be signs of failing API requests there.

Comment: @JonathanSteele The android code is only a post request to the server and then reads the clientsecret as result. Thanks for letting me know about the dashboard logs, I checked and it's completely empty. It's hard to add any logging because the program gets stuck at paymentIntent.create()

Comment: Add a try/catch and see what error/exception is happening when that line is reached. https://www.javatpoint.com/try-catch-block // https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=java